# Is there any way to track Knockout Observable Array item is displayed in UI?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using foreach with pagination for displaying the notification list to the user. Now I want to know whether the item is displayed for the user in screen enough time to update the notification status from New to Viewed. I cannot update it to all the rendered item since some of the items might not be displayed since I am using pagination also I want to mark it as updated after displaying it enough time(Eg 5 sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout has a very handy [`rateLimit`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) extension you can use to perform delayed updates. By creating a computed copy of your current page observable, and extending it to only notify you *5 seconds after it has stopped changing*, you can update the items on that page to a `read` status. For example:

```
var delayedPage = ko.computed(function() {
  // Loop through the items that are rendered (a computed of `page`)
  // Note: this makes the computed impure
  itemsOnDisplay().forEach(function(item) {
    // Set an observable status property of their viewmodel
    item.read(true);
  });

  // This creates the subscription to page changes
  return page();
}, this).extend({ 
  rateLimit: { 
    timeout: 5000, 
    method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" 
  }
});
```

In a working example:

- A collection of items with a boolean `read` observable
- An observable `page` property that tells us what page we're on
- A computed set of `itemsOnDisplay` that holds the items that are currently rendered
- A rate limited reflection of the current page that updates 5 seconds after the last page change

```js
var ViewModel = function(data) {
  this.itemsPerPage = 6;
  this.page = ko.observable();
  this.items = ko.observableArray(data); 
    
 
  this.displayItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var start = this.page() * this.itemsPerPage;
    var end = start + this.itemsPerPage;
    return this.items().slice(start, end);
  }, this);
  
  this.canGoBack = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.page() > 0;
  }, this);
  
  this.canGoForward = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return (this.page() + 1) * this.itemsPerPage < this.items().length;
  }, this);
  
  // The important part:
  this.delayedPage = ko.computed(function() {
    var currentPage = this.page();
    if (typeof currentPage === "undefined") return null;
    
    this.displayItems().forEach(function(item) {
      item.read(true);
    });
    
    console.log("Read items on page " + currentPage);
    return currentPage;
  }, this).extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 5000, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });
    
  this.page(0);
  
}

ViewModel.prototype.prev = function() {
  this.page(Math.max(this.page() - 1, 0));
};

            
ViewModel.prototype.next = function() {
  this.page(Math.min(this.page() + 1, Math.ceil(this.items().length / this.itemsPerPage)));
};

            
            
            
var myData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
  myData.push({
    label: "Item " + i,
    read: ko.observable(false)
  });
}

var vm = new ViewModel(myData);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
li::after {
  content: "new";
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  background: orange;
}

.is-read {
  background: #efefef;
}

.is-read::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: displayItems">
  <li data-bind="text: label, css: {'is-read': read }"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: prev, enable: canGoBack">prev</button>
<button data-bind="click: next, enable: canGoForward">next</button>
```

Comment: This is what exactly I was expecting for.